# Почему нет разницы между причастными оборотами?

Tags: причастный-оборот

Здравствуйте.

**Дятел, долбящий дерево.**

**Лес, засыпанный снегом.**

В первом случае можно задать вопрос "что делающий?", а во втором нельзя.

В первом случае видна прямая зависимость между определяемым словом и причастием (дятел долбит), а во втором нет.

Но эти обороты попадают под одинаковые правила только потому, что отвечают на вопрос "какой?".

То есть степень зависимости слов друг от друга не учитывается.

Неужели в русском языке нет никакой разницы  для таких случаев?

**Оновление**

Не могу поверить, что в "великом и могучем" такие случаи не рассматривались. Неужели всё под одну гребенку? Я вижу большую разницу в толковании этих примеров. Но это одно и то же по правилам русского языка.

Comment: Вопрос неплохой, но непонятный: какая вам нужна разница?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Вы о какой разнице? Пунктуационной? А зачем она? Любой причастный оборот, независимо от того, участвует в нём действительное причастие или страдательное, обособляется, если удовлетворяет условиям обособления (стоит после определяемого слова, относится к личному местоимению, имеет добавочное обстоятельственное значение, отстоит далеко от определяемого слова).

Или они называться должны по-разному - оборот субъектный и объектный? Там вся разница только в этом.

Дятел, долбящий дерево. - прич. оборот характеризует определяемое слово как субъект действия.

Лес, засыпанный снегом. - прич. оборот характеризует определяемое слово как объект действия.

А какой смысл их разделять, если и тот, и другой обосабливается? Если нужен глубокий анализ, тогда указывают на залог причастия (действительный или страдательный).

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрим, как строятся  предложения с обособленными оборотами:

(1) Дятел сидит на ветке.  Дятел, долбящий дерево, сидит на ветке. Сравнить: Дятел, который долбит  дерево, сидит на ветке.
(2)Лес кажется волшебным. Лес, засыпанный снегом, кажется волшебным. Сравнить: Лес, который засыпало снегом, кажется волшебным.

Обособленный оборот связан с подлежащим полупредикативной связью и описывает ДВЕ СИТУАЦИИ (с основным и добавочным действием):  (1) дятел сидит на ветке и дятел долбит дерево. (2) лес кажется волшебным и лес засыпало снегом.

Вид причастия определяет  активный или пассивный характер ДОБАВОЧНОГО действия:  действительное причастие – субъект сам совершает/ совершил действие, страдательное причастие – над ним совершается/совершено действие.

Answer (score 1):

Извините, за интимный вопрос: verzatrana, а какой язык для вас родной? Если в вашем  родном языке это различие существенно и выражается специальными способами, тогда ваш диссонанс понятен.  Каждый язык по-своему велик и могуч, в каждом есть средства выражения, отсутствующие в другом.  Причастные обороты – это, в каком-то смысле, маргинальная часть языка, Они  встречаются только в письменной речи.

Answer (score 0):

> > В первом случае видна прямая зависимость между определяемым словом и причастием (дятел долбит), а во втором нет.

Почему же... Лес засыпали.

Да, часто признаки прилагательного в причастии "главнее", чем глагольные признаки. Именно вопрос "какой?" всё и решает. А так как определение стоит после определяемого слова, то нужно обособление.

Comment: Лес,засыпанный снегом.>Снег засыпал. Связь между "засыпал" и "снег". Дятел долбит дерево.>Дятел долбит. Связь между "дятел" и "долбит".

Такие моменты вызывают у меня когнитивный диссонанс.Правила говорят,что это все одинаковые причастные обороты,а интуитивно представляется другое.И я начинаю тормозить с постановками знаков и т.д.

Comment: А что бы вы хотели? Во втором случае не ставить запятую? Ну, не ставьте — будет ошибка. Зато когнитивного диссонанса не будет — это ведь гораздо важнее? )))

Comment: Вот и интересует,почему нет различий:)Чем обосновано и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Что делающий лес? Пребывающий в состоянии засыпанности! Помимо того, что причастие при лесе страдательное, оно ещё и совершенного вида (лес уже засыпан, а дятел всё ещё долбит), иначе он бы был "лесом, засыпаемым снегом". 
Если запятые беспокоят, от них можно избавиться:

В засыпанном снегом лесу
Долбившийся в дерево дятел
Не знал, что подкрался барсук -
Что зря он усилия тратил.

Answer (score 0):

Что делающий лес? Пребывающий в состоянии засыпанности! Помимо того, что причастие при лесе страдательное, оно ещё и совершенного вида (лес уже засыпан, а дятел всё ещё долбит), иначе он бы был "лесом, засыпаемым снегом". 
Если запятые беспокоят, от них можно избавиться:

В засыпанном снегом лесу
Долбившийся в дерево дятел
Не знал, что подкрался барсук -
Что зря он усилия тратил.